# How to copy/paste rows based on matching criterias in 2 columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the alteration of the code from Scott Craner (which works perfectly). However, now I would like VBA to match criteria not only from one column but from 2 columns and then copy/paste as formulas to the next sheet.

```
Sub TransferRows()
Dim lLRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Cat"
        .Range("B2:B" & lLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlFormulas
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
 End Sub
```

Criteria1 in column "B" is "Cat", I need to add another Criteria2 ("dog") from column "C". So whenever I have "Cat" in "B" and "Dog" in "C" the entire rows are copied to Sheet2. PS. Bear in mind that I have various types of data in columns "B" and "C" so filters are imperative (also since there are 10's of thousands of rows I can't use the loop as it takes too long). Thus I would welcome advice on how to add another criteria to the aforementioned code.

Thanks
West

Comment: Basically, "cat" needs to be copied only when there is a "dog" in a cell in the same row. Also, I don't want the code to focus on the "adjacent cell" cos on occasions I have a "dog" in some other column in the sheet (i.e. not column "C").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below (see comments inside the code):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferRows()

Dim lLRow As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("B1:C" & lLRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Cat"
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="dog"
    End With    
    .Range("B2:C" & lLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy   

    ' rest of your code goes here
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add .EntireRow to one instance in your code but other than that it works perfectly! Thanks